# Why is a statically-linked "hello world" program so big (over 650 KB)?

Tags: c, static-linking, size-reduction, binary-size

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  printf("hello world\n");
  return 0;
}
```

If I build it with GCC, optimizing for size, and with static linking, and then strip it for further size minimization (maybe):

```
$ gcc -Os -static hello.c -o hello
$ strip hello
```

I get an executable of size ~695 KB.

Why is it so big? I realize it's not *just* my object code, and that there are stubs and what-not, but still, that's kind of huge.

Notes:

- OS:  Devuan GNU/Linux Chimaera (~= Debian Bullseye)
- Compiler: GCC 10.2
- libc: glibc 2.31-13
- Processor architecture: x86_64
- It doesn't improve if I build with `-O3 -flto`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243635/discussion-on-question-by-einpoklum-why-is-a-statically-linked-hello-world-pro).

Answer (score 4):

A partial answer: The executable's inflated size...

- does **not** have anything to do with your use of `printf`.
- does **not** have anything to do with the compiler's ability to optimize your code.
- does **not** have anything to do with your inclusion of `<stdio.h>`.

Why? Because even if you compile an empty program:

```
int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

You still get the same 695 KB executable.

<sub>Thanks @SparKot for the comment indicating this direction.</sub>

Comment: More explain why?

Comment: @Salem: The smaller program here doesn't do any of the three things I've listed - so they're not the cause of the inflated size.

Comment: So `C` compiler if you add  `-static` to it parameters will include all these functions just in case? I thought the size increase is due to backward compatibility with earlier version of Linux, or for bare metal Linux kernel  without using any System basic Libraries e.g `glibc`

Comment: @Salem: The executable will include the code for a bunch of functions, yes. No, it's not about backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally the issue here is that GNU libc isn't designed to be statically linked, which means, among other things, that the developers have not spent any time on reducing the size of statically-linked binaries.

I compiled your program with `-static` and also the special compiler argument `-Wl,-Map,a.map` which asks the linker to write out a file `a.map` (you can put any name you like after the second comma in that incantation) that explains why each object file was included in the link.  These are the first few lines of that file, edited slightly for readability:

```
Archive member included to satisfy reference by file (symbol)

/usr/lib/libc.a(libc-start.o)
                              /usr/lib/crt1.o (__libc_start_main)
/usr/lib/libc.a(check_fds.o)
                              /usr/lib/libc.a(libc-start.o) (__libc_check_standard_fds)
/usr/lib/libc.a(libc-tls.o)
                              /usr/lib/libc.a(libc-start.o) (__libc_setup_tls)
/usr/lib/libc.a(errno.o)
                              /usr/lib/libc.a(check_fds.o) (__libc_errno)
/usr/lib/libc.a(assert.o)
                              /usr/lib/libc.a(libc-start.o) (__assert_fail)
/usr/lib/libc.a(dcgettext.o)
                              /usr/lib/libc.a(assert.o) (__dcgettext)
```

What this means is that *before the linker even **looked** at the code to your program*, while it was still processing the transitive dependencies of the function that *calls* `main`, it needed to pull in the code that prints assertion failure messages, and *that* code pulls in the code for dynamically loading and printing localized (translated into the user's native language) error messages.  It looks like the bulk of your 600K of binary executable is that code and its dependencies, including among other things all of `malloc`, all of `fprintf`, all of `iconv`, the parser for `gettext` "message object" files, ...

Comment: But why doesn't the linker drop most of this stuff, when it knows it's not used in the program?

Comment: @einpoklum The linker does not know, and cannot know. There is startup code (part of the library implementation, crt1.o and crti.o and whatnot) and your code. The startup code is fixed and it has no idea what your code actually uses, but it needs to initialise everything your code (or any user code) *might* use. For example, should stdout be line buffered? This is set up by startup code. Your program might not be using stdout at all, but the startup code doesn't know and cannot know that. Can it be done differently, for example set it up on first use? Maybe, but glibc does what it does.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. But the linker knows what my code _does_ use (or possibly-uses, if my code is complex).  So if there's a bunch of code which initializes a symbol that is never used - why should the linker not be able to drop that code?

Comment: @einpoklum No, it does not know. It is dumb. It sees a list of objects. Here is an object. It runs initialisation of symbol X. Bring in symbol X. Here is another object. It does not use symbol X, but it has already been brought in, so it stays in. The linker doesn't care that the first object is startup code and the second object is your code. There is no mechanism to tell it that.

Comment: Expanding on what n.m. is saying, we have `__libc_start_main` (which is definitely used) conditionally calling `__assert_fail`. That call never actually happens (we know that because the program isn't crashing on startup)—but the compiler *failed* to prove that it can never happen (we know that because the call got emitted) and the linker only knows that there's an undefined reference that needs satisfied.

Comment: @einpoklum As others said, the issue is that glibc's method for iconv, nss, etc, is bloated and designed such that it cannot really be eliminated. However, the linker "can" be made "smarter" with LTO (-flto), garbage collection (-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-dections), and a great many other but less easily done/less reduction tricks, but I wouldn't expect more than a 20 to 30% size reduction, max.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use `-static` on compiling your code?

You compiled your code to be a static executable, so it linked all libraries (e.g. stdio) from `libc.a`, extracting the used modules and linking them inside the program code, instead of linking from `libc.so`.  `printf()` (and many of the standard functions) unfortunately is a complex routine, that deals with buffering of input/output and makes your executable far bigger when you have to include the code in your program.

If, on the other side, you allow your linker to do **dynamic linking**, you'll get a dynamic executable around 16 kb and no extra loading work, as the libc is always preloaded for you in system memory  (because almost every program uses it, so it is loaded as soon as the first program linked dynamically in the system starts -- e.g. `systemd` or `init`).  The kernel has no need to load the standard library if it is a shared object, as it is normally already loaded when your program start.  This doesn't happen when you link a program statically.  The used code of the library is included in your executable, but as no shared code is present on it... the full megabyte has to be loaded in memory from the executable file, with a loading on start penalty in performance.

You can get still under that size, but for that you have to do it in assembler and not link the standard c library and runtime module.

The next program, in assembler, reduces to 8488 bytes.   besides the code used is only the following bytes (after disassembling) the rest is for ELF compliance (default relocation tables etc.)

```
  401000:   b8 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%eax
  401005:   bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
  40100a:   b9 00 20 40 00          mov    $0x402000,%ecx
  40100f:   ba 0d 00 00 00          mov    $0xd,%edx
  401014:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
  401016:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  40101b:   bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
  401020:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

the listing is:

## hello.s

```
.globl _start
.section .data
output:
    .ascii "Hello, world\n"
output_end:
.section .text
_start:
    movl $4, %eax      ; system call (4, write)
    movl $1, %ebx      ; output descriptor (stdout, 1)
    movl $output, %ecx ; output string (above)
    movl $(output_end - output), %edx     ; string size
    int $0x80          ; system call.
    movl $1, %eax      ; system call (1, exit)
    movl $0, %ebx      ; exit code (0)
    int $0x80          ; system call.
```

just 34 bytes program, but the executable is still 8kb after stripping.  This is because it is formatted as an ELF binary executable, and this requires some extra data space for the empty symbol tables and the like (some sections are padded to a full page of code, probably one page for the `.text` section, and another for the `.data` section)

On the other side, if you want to see what is including in the linking phase, add `-v` to the compiler call, so it prints the command line used to call the linker, and you will see everything that is linked in the final executable.

To compile/link the above program, just do:

```sh
$ as hello.s -o hello.o
$ ld -o hello hello.o
$ ./hello
Hello, world
$ _
```

Comment: I read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/04/04/comparing-go-vs-c-in-embedded-applications/) where they were statically linking to try to make an apples-to-apples comparison (although that's not what's achieved), and it got me wondering about it. Also, while I'm sure you can get a much smaller executable, that's not what I asked.

Comment: as you have been told, the standard library has not been designed to be linked as an `.a` library.  This is because the number of advantages related to link to it dynamically is so hughe that there's almost nothing to argue in favor of a static link.  This means that all modules are merged into just a few, and the `.a` library only contains a few modules.  By the way, you don't specify the reasons you want to use that option.  Should I guess?  Do I actually deserve to be downvoted for not gessing that?