# How to build a standalone C ELF binary without installing libraries on a remote machine?

Tags: c, bash, gcc

I am trying to build a C ELF binary on linux and try to execute it directly on another machine. (Sent via scp linux command)

The problem is that even when I build the ELF binary with all needed libs, when I try to execute it on the remote machine, I got this error:

```
/tmp/25636: error while loading shared libraries: libnftnl.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Since I can't execute `sudo apt install -y libfuse-dev libmnl-dev  libnftnl-dev` to install my libs on the remote machine , I wanted to know if it was possible to package all the dependancies within the ELF binary, so that the ELF binary can be executed in a standalone way.

[image]

bguess.

Comment: You can use `-static` flag to embed all necessary `shared-library` in `ELF` binary.

Comment: Check [statically-linked-hello-world-program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71755641/)

Comment: GCC didn't find`libmnl.a` on the system. You can link statically link only those libraries which can't be found/installed on `target system`.

Comment: Where is the file called **exactly** `libmnl.a`? Not `libmnl`, not `libmnl.so`, not anything else. `libmnl.a`.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to use Conan to manage the dependencies, it will download and compile all dependencies as static libraries, all you need to do is to write a file with the toolchain path and another with the libraries and versions you want.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I finally grab it from the internet, I added it to the `lib` folder  and added `-Llib -lnftnl -lmnl` to use it

Comment: @जलजनक answer in the next 13hours to earn the bounty man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@जलजनक was right. adding the `-static` flag works, but the thing is that you have to add it at the right place !

For me it was right after the `-o OUTPUT_FILE` and before `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.

Thank you all for your help.